# What does "of who Americans" mean in this sentence: "This challenges the very essence of who Americans are as as a people"?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

> This challenges the very essence of who Americans are as a people.

What does "of who Americans" mean?
This sentence originates from the newspaper The Economist.

Comment: I am confused about the word "who". I can figure out it is an attributive clause, but I could  not understand why "who" is put before "Americans".

Comment: You parse it wrong, it might help if read it this way  "this challenges" --what is challenged? : " the very essence of something"  --the essence of what thing? : "of who we are" --what's the "we" standing for?  "Americans".= "the very essence of who Americans are"

Comment: Compare 'What is your understanding of what angels are?'

Answer (score 3):

The way to understand the sentence is this.

The object of the sentence is "who Americans are", a phrase similar to "who I am", and meaning 'the identify of Americans'.

Specifically it is "who Americans are as a people", i.e. the American national identity.More specifically it is "the very essence" of that, i.e. the fundamental nature of American identity.

'This' (whatever it is) challenges that.

Comment: how to understand the word "who"

Comment: "who Americans are" means the identify of Americans. Another example might be "I support Manchester united. That is **who I am**".

Comment: who Americans are . is  similar to   who I  am.  I got it, thanks!